# Inspect the loading from the beginning to debug an Excel add-in

Tags: ms-office, office-js, office-app

I have an Excel add-in in AppSource. It has a bug: sometimes, when the add-in is launched via its button on Ribbon for the first time, the first page cannot be well loaded (thus there is just a blanc taskpane). Clicking on the button once again loads well the add-in.

I want to see how files are loaded while the add-in is being launched for the first time, and follow [this method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/debug-office-add-ins-on-ipad-and-mac) to debug:

> Then, open the Office application and sideload your add-in.
>   Right-click the add-in and you should see an Inspect Element option in
>   the context menu. Select that option and it will pop the Inspector,
>   where you can set breakpoints and debug your add-in.

The problem of this approach is that we can only trigger the "Inspect Element" when the loading has finished. Then in the `Network` tab, we see all the files have already been loaded with no further information (e.g., time, size). This approach does not allow me to inspect the loading from the beginning:

[image]

Does anyone have a better way or better tool?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried typing `window.location.reload()` in the Console and pressing enter?  At least on Windows, I have found this to be a very useful debugging technique for diagnosing issues that happen during the taskpane launch -- and it feels like it should force the JS files to be reloaded as well, for the scenario you're looking for.

Comment: Hello Michael, `window.location.reload()` does reload the add-in and JS files. But it is still not the first-time launching. Whereas in Windows, if we open `F12` before the add-in, launch the add-in, then keep refreshing F12, then choose the add-in, we can inspect the information of the first-time launching.

Comment: And on my side, the first-time launching does have subtle difference from the second/third time launching. For exemple, the welcome page cannot be well loaded for the first time, but a second-time launching amends that.